# Disable scientific notation in vb6

Tags: vb6

How to disable scientific notation in vb6.

Ex:if i assign a variable like this

a=170000000113123123

It changes to

a = 1.70000000113123E+17

After pressing enter.How can we avoid this?

Comment: The floating point format you are using doesn't have enough precision to store that number, so scientific notation is used to show the number, with less precision.

Comment: @ Delan Azabani,I am using double data type to store the number

Comment: @ Delan Azabani,suggest me which data type should i use to retain the original format.

Comment: Do you have an arbitrary-precision floating point data type?

Answer (score 1):

I tried with variant type as below.

dim a as variant

a=cdec("170000000113123123").

Debug.print a  'displays 170000000113123123

Am i doing the right thing?

Answer (score 0):

VB6 does not support literal values of that precision/size.

From the [data type summary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263420%28v=VS.60%29.aspx) a single is limited to ~8 significant figures while doubles are limited to ~15 significant figures.

You will need to find a large number library to work with numbers that large.